# Where can I find the drivers of a Unix printer? (Arch)

Tags: arch-linux, cups, printer, avahi

Earlier today I went to the AUR repository and downloaded this driver https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/brother-hll2340dw/ for my printer.

It turns out, I didn't even need a driver at all and Avahi/CUPS was able to detect my printer.

But now I am stuck with a really annoying problem; some programs like Libre Office are recognizing two printers, one of which does not work.

The printer is listed a `UNIX printer` by `avahi-browse`, with service type `_printer._tcp`.

I would really just like to find wherever the service is coming from and delete it.

Answer (score 1):

As described in [RFC6763](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6763) and [Bonjour Printing Specification](https://developer.apple.com/bonjour/printing-specification/bonjourprinting-1.2.1.pdf), service type `_printer._tcp` is the "flagship name" for printing. The idea is apparently that you can find all printers and print services of any type by searching for `_printer._tcp` service.

More formally, the `_printer._tcp` service type refers to Unix LPD printing protocol that can normally found in TCP port 515 on supporting network printers and print servers. But if a printer does not support LPD or has LPD support disabled, it should still announce `_printer._tcp`, but with a port number of 0.

Use `avahi-discover` or `avahi-browse -r _printer._tcp` to find the IP address and port associated with that service. You may find that it's coming either from the printer itself, or from your CUPS if it's configured to allow sharing of any configured printers.

Since Brother HL-L2340DW apparently supports AirPrint, the printer itself is the likely source. If the auto-detection results in a non-functional printer entry in applications, you could configure your CUPS to not auto-discover printers. In my version of CUPS (Debian 9), this could be done by stopping `cups-browsed`, editing `/etc/cups/cups-browsed.conf` to set `BrowseRemoteProtocols` to `none`, and restarting `cups-browsed`.

Alternatively, you could use `BrowseDeny <printer's IP address>` in the same file to explicitly mask out the auto-discovered entry for that particular printer, while still keeping the printer auto-discovery feature in general.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was sure you were right until I could not get the printer to disable when I was disabling the CUPS service. However, disabling Avahi DID disable the printer.